# Remove whitespace after item in description

Tags: spacing, description

how can I remove the whitespace after the item in the description?

Example: this code:

```
\begin{description}

\item[First]\footnote{Here goes the footnote} lorem ipsum ...

\item[Second], which is my second item, lorem ipsum ...

\end{description}
```

produces sth like that:

**First** [1] lorem ipsum ...

**Second** , which is my second item, lorem ipsum ...

I would like to have the whitespace between First and the footnote, and between Second and the comma removed. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with the package [enumitem](http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) and set `labelsep` to zero.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[labelsep=0ex]

\item[First]\footnote{Here goes the footnote} lorem ipsum ...

\item[Second], which is my second item, lorem ipsum ...

\end{description}
\end{document}
```